# Differentiate between "this" as Class object instance and event trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
var ajxCustomer = Class.create({
    init: function() {
        this.miniLoginForm = new VarienForm('login-form', true);
        jQuery("#mini-register button.button").on('click', { el: this }, this.ajxLogReg);
    },
    ajxLogReg: function(e) {
        var form = this.miniLoginForm;
    }
})
```

In this example, I am trying to use `this` to get class instance, and assigned variable, however `this` returns the element that fired the click event, instead. How can I use the class object in my example?

Comment: Please refer it as object instance, JavaScript (as of now) has no classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/) method to switch the context of `this`

```
jQuery("...").on('click', $.proxy(this.ajxLogReg, this));
```

When `ajxLogReg` is executed, `this` will refer to whichever instance you pass in (in your case, `ajxCustomer`)

Answer (score 0):

because context is changing so you can solve your problem

```
this.miniLoginForm = new VarienForm('login-form', true);
var me = this;
jQuery("#mini-register button.button").on('click',{el:this},me.ajxLogReg);
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is storing the `this` when it points to the object instance to a different variable - usually it is named `self`.

```
var self = this;
self.miniLoginForm = new VarienForm('login-form', true);
$("#mini-register button.button").on('click', { el: self }, this.ajxLogReg);
```

Another naming scheme, that I see often is using `var that = this;`. This can be considered a well-spread JavaScript design pattern.